# Stopping ipcluster engines (IPython Parallel)

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel

How do I stop the engines that have been started with:

`ipcluster engines --n=8 --daemonize`

The currently running processes look like:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ipcluster engines --n=8 --daemonize
/usr/bin/python -m IPython.parallel.engine --profile-dir /home/ubuntu/.ipython/profile_default --cluster-id  --log-to-file --log-level=20
```

I do not want to run `killall python`.

Answer (score 1):

From a Client, you can call `shutdown`:

```
import IPython.parallel as ipp
rc = ipp.Client()
# shutdown specific engines
rc.shutdown([1, 5])
# shutdown all engines:
rc.shutdown()
# shutdown everything, including the Hub
rc.shutdown(hub=True)
```

Comment: Anyway to do this from the `CLI`? Ditto for the engines started on the master using `/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ipcluster start --n=7 --delay=5 --daemonize`? I ask because [StarCluster seems to be incorrectly stoping the engines](https://github.com/jtriley/StarCluster/issues/538).

Comment: `ipcluster stop` should shutdown everything. But there is no CLI API for doing anything selective.

Comment: (it may take a little while for engines not started with the controller to come down after `ipcluster stop`, since it takes some heartbeat cycles for them to notice, but they will bring themselves down.

Comment: After shutdown() it still running, CPU 100% in my case.